# Geoserver WMS does not find a point with mixed geometry

Tags: geometry, geoserver, wms, getfeatureinfo

I created a layer with mixed geometry. This layer contains ring and point geometry. When I click on the ring geometry, it returns object data, but if I click on the center point, there is no data. What can be done to make it work?

I tried to unite two layers into groups and try to do this, it worked. But according to business logic, I can’t do that.
[OpenLayers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsbGe.png)

[Style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dC90W.png)

Comment: Basically best practice is not to do this, there are hints in the manual if you must do it

Comment: Can I have a link to this manual?

Comment: where it has always been - https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/tipstricks/mixed-geometries.html

Comment: It's written about styles, but there's no way to get data when applying it to a point

Comment: What you click on is determined by the style

Comment: What do I need to change in the style to make it work? Style added to the question

Comment: is this a WFS layer or a WMS layer?

Comment: Sorry, there's a typo in the description. WMS layer